# Timer's cycle and end cycle

Tags: actionscript-3

1). This timer was designed to wait for the cation on stage to be finished and then to go to the next frame. The problem is that in the `function finishMove` each condition runs only after the previous condition completed the full timer's cycle. so the first `removeChild(gdropBall2);` happens immediately, but  `removeChild(Wall2Missing);` get deleted 2 seconds later and the last `removeChild(gdropBall1);` get deleted 2 seconds after that. I want it all happened at the same time. How do I do that?

2). the `function stopTimer` was supposed to stop the timer but I'm not sure that it does, I had to put the conditions in `function finishMove` because it errors on Child not found after it's been removed in the first timer's cycle.

```
var timer2: Timer = new Timer(2000);
timer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, finishMove);

function checkScoreScene10(): void {
  if (scoreScene10 >= 300) {
  timer2.start();
  }
}

function finishMove(e: TimerEvent): void {
  if (stage.contains(gdropBall2)) {
  removeChild(gdropBall2);
  } else if (stage.contains(Wall2Missing)) {
  removeChild(Wall2Missing);
  } else if (stage.contains(gdropBall1)) {
  removeChild(gdropBall1);
  gotoAndStop(2);
  }

  function stopTimer(event: TimerEvent): void {
  timer2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopTimer);
  timer2 = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `if/else` the conditional check stops after it encounters a true statement. So it's only going on the check for the second if statement if the first is false. You can remove the `else` statements to make it check for all three in the same loop (see below).

Your `stopTimer` function is confusing to me. Are you ever adding that function as a handler for the timer event?

If you want to stop the timer first call `stop()`, then remove any event listeners, then you can set the variable to null. In my example I just call a function that does that directly:

```
function finishMove(e: TimerEvent): void {
    if (stage.contains(gdropBall2)) {
       removeChild(gdropBall2);
    } 

    if (stage.contains(Wall2Missing)) {
       removeChild(Wall2Missing);
    } 

    if (stage.contains(gdropBall1)) {
       removeChild(gdropBall1);
       gotoAndStop(2);
    }

    stopTimer();
}

function stopTimer():void {
    timer2.stop();
    timer2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, finishMove);
    timer2 = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stopTimer-function is never be called... adding the EventListener for the handler `stopTimer` I can not see anywhere...
for the stop-function try this:

```
function stopTimer(event: TimerEvent): void {
    timer2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, finishMove);
    timer2.stop();
}
```

But be sure to call it ;-)